# C# Cannot convert `char' expression to type `string'

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, c#-4.0

I have this code:

```
public class Kata
{
  public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
  {
     //add variale to hold final result
     int finalResult = 0;
     //get the length of the value input
     int valLength = value.ToString().Length;
     //convert value given into an array of ints
     string valString = value.ToString();
     //iterate over each number and multiply that number by the length of value input
     for (int i=0; i < valLength; i++) {
        //convert char at index[i] of stringified value to int and mutiply by # of digits, store to result
        finalResult += int.Parse(valString[i]) * valLength;
     }
     //return the result
     return finalResult == value;
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error when I run this that I understand, but don't quite know how to fix. My goal is to take a number (i.e 1234) and multiply each number by the total number of digits it contains (i.e 1*4 + 2*4 + 3*4...etc).

Comment: cannot read code not formatted as code

Comment: You are converting back and forth between int and string a bunch, why?  What is the exact error/issue you get?

Comment: You can avoid the string altogether if you use `%10` to get the leas significant digit and `/10` to truncate the least significant digit.

Comment: have my +1 for making us familiar with the concept of [narcissistic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number): should it not be to the power of the number of digits instead of the * length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valString[i]` will be a `char` - because that's what indexing does to a string. `int.Parse` expects a string. The simplest thing to do would probably just

```
finalResult += int.Parse(valString[i].ToString()) * valLength;
```

Assuming to turn a single character digit into a one-digit integer is your intention.

This is less "dangerous" than the traditional hack of subtracting '0' because you can rely on int.Parse to throw an exception if the char is anything but numeric.

You will also need to make the input argument `uint`, or define a behavior for negative numbers.

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you did there! That's exactly what I'm attempting to do. Using a for loop, take each character in the string and convert it to an int. Will try this out and get back to you

Comment: I must admit I did not attempt to understand the algorithm behind it - the actual computation can likely be done in a one-liner, but that's a different story for them over at codegolf.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have just Latin digit characters 0 to 9, you could use `(valString[i] - '0')` instead of `int.Parse(valString[i])`.

`valString[i]` is a char, not a string (which `int.Parse()` would expect). And chars are automatically converted to their Unicode integer code in C#, and as thhe digits 0 to 9 have consecutive Unicode values, `'0' - '0'` would be the Unicode value of the character for the digit 0 minus itself, i.  e. 0, and so on up to `'9' - '0'` being 9 more than 0, i. e. 9.

This code would not work if there could be non Latin digits or non digit characters in your string. And looking at your complete code, the assumption should be met, as actually, you are converting from an int.

Comment: the trivial case would be a negative int, the - sign would be invalid input. OP should define as `uint` or add exception handling, or define a behavior for negative numbers.

Comment: @dlatikay good point!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better option that avoids strings altogether

```
public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
{
    if(value < 0) return false;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(value>0)
    {
        sum += value%10;
        value /= 10;
        count++;
    }

    return value == (sum*count);
}
```

Basically the `value%10` will give you the least significate digit.  Then the `value /= 10;` will truncate that digit.  Once `value` is zero you've seen all the digits.  And your formula (4*1 + 4*2 + 4*3 + 4*4) can of course just be 4*(1+2+3+4), which is the sum of the digits times the number of digits.

And presumably no negative number would be "Narcissistic" so you can just return `false` for them.

Comment: This is by far the best answer for the question as written... though I suspect his interpretation of "narcissistic" is wrong, such that he should be raising to the power of the length, making a negative number a possible contender. Of course, mine doesn't handle that well, either.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Actually narcissistic numbers would not be negative since individual digits would not be considered negative.

Answer (score -1):

`int.Parse()` expects a string, but `valString[i]` is a character. You *could* just change this to `valString[i].ToString()`, but rather than parsing you can take advantage of the fact that the digit characters are encoded in sequence by casting them to `int` and subtracting the value of the `0` integer:

```
public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
{ 
    int zero = (int)'0';
    string valueString = value.ToString();
    int total = 0;

    foreach(char c in valueString)
    {
       int digit = ((int)c - zero);
       total += digit * valueString.Length;
    }

    return total == value; 
}
```

or

```
public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
{ 
    int zero = (int)'0';
    string valueString = value.ToString();

    return valueString.Select(c => (c - zero) * valueString.Length).Sum() == value; 
}
```

If you really want to you can write the second option as a one-liner:

```
public static bool Narcissistic(int value)
{ 
    return value.ToString().Select(c => c - '0').Sum() * value.ToString().Length == value; 
}
```

Comment: @juharr I mis-read the question at first. This should be much better now.